# How do distribute n points inside a circle according to given "relative probability" for each of having a certain distance from a circle center?

Tags: c++, algorithm, probability

I'm not good in terms of probability theory. Here's what I'm trying to do:

I want to place `PERCEPTORS_NUMBER` points inside a circle

I have `unnormalized_distribution(r)` function. If we consider two circle radiuses `r1` and `r2`  then:

[image]

equals to

[image]

Let's call the point's distance from the circle center its radius

All points will have radiuses in range [0;`FOCUS_RADIUS`].  Each point's radius is equals to i/`DISTRIBUTION_DISCRETIZATION_FREQUENCY` where `i` is integer

I can count `unnormalized_distribution` for each possible radius, then divide it by sums of `unnormalized_distribution`'s for all radiuses.

```
ld distribution_integral=0;
ld probabilities[FOCUS_RADIUS*DISTRIBUTION_DISCRETIZATION_FREQUENCY+1];
for(int i=0;i<=FOCUS_RADIUS*DISTRIBUTION_DISCRETIZATION_FREQUENCY;++i)
{
    distribution_integral+=probabilities[i]=unnormalized_distribution(((ld)i)/DISTRIBUTION_DISCRETIZATION_FREQUENCY);

}
for(int i=0;i<=FOCUS_RADIUS*DISTRIBUTION_DISCRETIZATION_FREQUENCY;++i)
{
    probabilities[i]/=distribution_integral;
}
```

Then for each radius I'll have the probability in range [0;1] that a certain point will have it. The sum of all probabilities will be 1

For a given point, how can I choose a radius according to this probability?

---

Update: Solution code:

```
ld distribution_integral=0;
ld probabilities_sums[FOCUS_RADIUS*DISTRIBUTION_DISCRETIZATION_FREQUENCY+1];
for(int i=0;i<=FOCUS_RADIUS*DISTRIBUTION_DISCRETIZATION_FREQUENCY;++i)
{
    distribution_integral+=probabilities_sums[i]=unnormalized_distribution(((ld)i)/DISTRIBUTION_DISCRETIZATION_FREQUENCY);

}
for(int i=0;i<=FOCUS_RADIUS*DISTRIBUTION_DISCRETIZATION_FREQUENCY;++i)
{
    probabilities_sums[i]/=distribution_integral;
    if(i!=0)
        probabilities_sums[i]+=probabilities_sums[i-1];
}
srand(time(0));
ld chosen_x_list[PERCEPTORS_NUMBER];
ld chosen_y_list[PERCEPTORS_NUMBER];
for(int i=0;i<PERCEPTORS_NUMBER;++i)
{

    ld random_value=((double)rand())/RAND_MAX;
    ld best_diff=2;
    int best_ind=0;
    int r=FOCUS_RADIUS*DISTRIBUTION_DISCRETIZATION_FREQUENCY,l=0,m;
    while(r>=l)
    {
        m=l+(r-l)/2;
        if(probabilities_sums[m]>random_value)
        {
            if(m==0)
                best_ind=0;
            else if(probabilities_sums[m-1]<=random_value)
                best_ind=m;

            r=m-1;
        }
        else
            l=m+1;
    }
    ld chosen_radius=((ld)best_ind)/DISTRIBUTION_DISCRETIZATION_FREQUENCY;
    ld chosen_angle=(ld)(rand()%360);
    fprintf(stderr,"%f\n",(float)chosen_angle);
    //chosen_angle=0;

    ld chosen_x,chosen_y;
    chosen_x_list[i]=chosen_radius*cos(dtr(chosen_angle));
    chosen_y_list[i]=chosen_radius*sin(dtr(chosen_angle));
}
printf("%d\n",PERCEPTORS_NUMBER);
for(int i=0;i<PERCEPTORS_NUMBER;++i)
{
    printf("%f %f\n",(float)chosen_x_list[i],(float)chosen_y_list[i]);
}
```

ld is defined with

```
typedef long double ld;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have an extra step of creating summation array:

```
aux[0] = 0
aux[i] = aux[i-1] + probabilities[i-1]
```

Note that this array is monotonically increasing, and `aux[i]-aux[i-1] = probabilities[i-1]`, and `probabilities[n] = 1`.

Draw a random real (or double) number in range `(0,1)` (let it be `r`), and choose the focus with index `i` such `that aux[i-1] <= r < aux[i]`.

The later can be done efficiently with [binary search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm), since your array is sorted.

So, by drawing a number with uniform distribution (0,1), it has exactly `aux[i]-aux[i-1] = probabilities[i]` chance to be in the range of element `i`.

Comment: Also I should choose first such i because aux[i] may be 0. Thank you!